# How to recursively delete self referencing class C++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, heap-memory, delete-operator

I have been scouring forums trying to understand how to recursively free all my memory from heap but the process is not completing.

The Game class is like a tree object, `map[2][8][8]` is the data on it. Game class represents a chess board and `*moves[64]` is an array of children Games.

My move generation function adds moves an increments roots to the amount of moves generated.

When I do `game.clear()` to delete all children, it deletes the lowest layer of children, but fails after. What is going wrong with my code? My thought process is that delete is called on Game game, which calls the destructor, in the destructor, it recursively loops through all moves until you are at the bottom layer, then just works its way back up.

```
class Game {
    public:
    char data[2][8][8];
    int roots = 0;
    Game *moves[64];

    ~Game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < roots; i++) {
            delete moves[i];
            moves[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < roots; i++) {
            delete moves[i];
            moves[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            delete[] map[i][j];
        }
        delete[] map[i];
    }
    delete[] map;
    private:
    ....
    void make_move(int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
        Game *move = new Game;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
                    (*move).map[i][x][y] = map[i][x][y];
        (*move).t = t + 1;
        if(map[0][x][y] == -map[0][x + dx][y + dy])
            (*move).h = h + map[1][x + dx][y + dy];
        (*move).map[0][x + dx][y + dy] = map[0][x][y];
        (*move).map[0][x][y] = 0;
        (*move).map[1][x + dx][y + dy] = map[1][x][y];
        (*move).map[1][x][y] = 0;
        moves[roots++] = move;
    }
}


int num = 0;
int paths = 0;
void benchmark(Game &game, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0)
        return;
    game.add_moves();
    for (int i = 0; i < game.roots; i++)
        benchmark(*game.moves[i], depth - 1);
    num += game.roots;
    paths++;
}
void print_benchmark(Game &game, int depth) {
    int t1 = clock();
    benchmark(game, 1);
    int t2 = clock();
    printf("num=%d, t=%.3f, mps=%.2f, paths=%d\n", num, (t2 - t1) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC, num / ((t2 - t1) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC), paths);
}

int main() {
    Game game;
    Handler io;

    io.set(game, "reset");
    print_benchmark(game, 5);

    game.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete &obj_gametree` looks *very* suspect, can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? You really need to show us some actual working code, your `GameTree` class doesn't make sense either, a `Game` destructor in a `GameTree` class?

Comment: Also, you do have a constructor which initializes `GameTree::moves`?

Comment: Shouldnt "delete[] moves" delete the array and therefore call all destructors of the array?

Comment: Keep your data in STL containers (e.g. like `vector`) and you do not need to care about destruction. Explicit `new` and `delete` is in many cases not the best way.

Comment: @Kellerspeicher I tried using lists and strings since they delete when they are out of reference, but it massively slowed my program.

Comment: @Anedar Yes thank you, I have just added that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg more code has been added, delete has been moved to delete a pointer, sorry about that, and also I didn't know a 3d char array would have to be initialized? I'm not to great at programming but isn't that allocated on the stack or something?

Comment: If STL is making things slow it is usually a matter of wrong usage. For example filling a `vector` by use of `push_back()` will reallocate frequently which is time consuming. Prior usage of `reserve()` is preventing it. In general STL containers are not slower than managing your memory yourself.

Comment: Every `new`  has to have an associated `delete` and vice versa. I don't see the `new` associated to `map` you delete in `clear()`. What is `map` by the way? Are `map` and `data` the same?
`data[][][]` is not on the heap, so `delete` on it is wrong

Comment: @Kellerspeicher I am trying to use vectors now. thank you for the suggestion. if you have time would you explain what you mean by push_back()? what function should I use to avoid constant reallocation?

Comment: @LucaPizzamiglio sorry for the confusion, data and map are the same, I just changed them. new is located at function make_move, and so does that mean map[][][] does not have to be deleted at all?

Comment: If you want to append a new entry at the end of a `vector` you can do that using [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). The vector is getting longer and needs more memory. If the reserved memory no longer is enough the container will reallocate to get more memory. This will slow down things. So if you know how much you will need, you should use [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) before. That is the difference between `capacity` and `size`.

Comment: @MichaelChoi map[][][] has not to be deleted, the Game object has to be deleted. In this case, map[][][] is part of the object itself.

Comment: @Kellerspeicher Hi, sorry to keep bothering you. I ran some benchmark tests to compare vectors with arrays and arrays seem to be outperforming, meaning I am doing something wrong, right? I am going to take your word that vectors and STLs are better but I am not sure why. I copied and pasted my class and changed the vector to an array, so they are algorithmically identical. In the constructor of the vector version, I reserved the same 64 slots. push_back is used. Here are the results (mps is moves per second):
moves=594365
vectors:
t=7.520, mps=79037.90
arrays:
t=1.775, mps=334853.52

Comment: Please update your question to use a consistent set of variable names, and so that we have something that compiles.

Comment: There is a little trade-off for the comfort of containers. But it shall not be more than factor 4 as in your case. This is a clear evidence that some thing is wrong. But it is hard to evaluate without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is a compromise between vector and array the [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/array.html). May be that better fits your needs. But I never used it.

Comment: So just a tip for getting your "code smell" sensors calibrated, deleting something you just took the address of is almost never correct. The only time I could think it'd be valid is to take the address of a bound reference that was dereferenced from a heap allocated pointer. But that's rare and itself a bit smelly, too. If I were to ever see a `delete &smth` without a comment that absolutely justifies its use, I'd really question the quality of the code. Just to give you an idea.